# Go--no buildable Go source file in

Tags: build, go

everyone. I have a problem with golang 's build.

The details:

I have a folder named "12" and creating a go source file named 12_test.go. Codes are below:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world")
}
```

.Then typing "go build 12_test.go". Something going wrong:

```
"go build command-line-arguments: no buildable Go source files in D:\12"
```

So,Could someone tell me why? Thanks and apology for my poor English.

Comment: In addition to what Simon answered; `go run foo.go` or `go build` (or `go install`) you shouldn't (normally) specify file names with `go build`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The suffix `_test` has special meaning in Go. It is where you put tests for your go programs. The build tool will ignore these completely .. they are run with `go test`.

Remove `_test` from the file name or just name it `test.go`.